# Input last active cell in row

Tags: excel, command

I keep finding answers to select last in COL but what i am looking for is how to make cell show last active cell in ROW

For example you set dates of when someone bought something and you dont want to look all the way to last active cell but have that one cell which updates with last active cells input and you know immediatly when that customer was last time contacted

http://i39.tinypic.com/2wnbrxy.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your question... Please can you clarify it a bit more....

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/2wnbrxy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
FinalRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
do While trim(cells(FinalRow,1)) = ""
FinalRow = FinalRow - 1
Loop
```

---

```
FinalColumn = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
Do While trim(Cells(1,FinalColumn)) <> ""
FinalColumn = FinalColum - 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all data is contiguous you could use something like this as a formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & COUNTA(A:A))
```

Otherwise you can get the last row in VBA like this:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```